# 4.4.8 in Petrovic

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

The question is given below:

[image]

But I do not know how to answer it, I feel like the function must be continuous, can anyone provide me with a counter example that say that the statement of the question is wrong?

Comment: You are being asked to prove that $f$ is constant, not continuous.

Comment: yes I know .... but do the given assumptions can proof it? @JohnDouma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot prove it, since it is false. Take, for instance$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&(-1,1)&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R\\&x&\mapsto&\begin{cases}0&\text{ if }x<0\\1&\text{ if }x\geqslant 0.\end{cases}\end{array}$$Then $f$ is right differentiable everywhere and $(\forall x\in[-1,1]):f_+'(x)=0$. However, $f$ is not constant.

Comment: I think the interval of -1 to 1 should be opened ..... am I correct?

Comment: I've edited my answer. I hope that everything is correct now.