# A difficulty in understanding a part of a solution of 4.4.4 Petovic

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

The question is given below:

[image]

**The answer is given by:**

No,Example: $y = x^3, c = 0.$

But I could not understand how this shows that there **does not exist** $x_{1}, x_{2}$ that satisfy the required, could anyone explain this for me please?

Comment: Your counter example is missing $a$ and $b$.

Comment: The interval need not be specified, Yuval Gat, since you can prove such $x_1, x_2$ don't exist without assuming an interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because if $x_1\neq x_2$, then ${x_1}^3\neq{x_2}^3$ and therefore $\dfrac{{x_1}^3-{x_2}^3}{x_1-x_2}\neq0=f'(0)$.

Comment: I don't think you need to consider the case $x_1=x_2$ since the statement clearly says "*two* points $x_1,x_2$".

Comment: Could you please check this question for me 
 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2986850/4-4-8-in-petrovic?noredirect=1#comment6163584_2986850  ?

Comment: True, 5xum, but it doesn't say two *distinct* points.

Comment: @5xum Yes, I agree.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

You need to prove that the statement "there exist $x_1,x_2$ such that somethingsomething" is false. You can do that by proving the negation of this statement, i.e. proving that for all $x_1,x_2$, somethingsomething is not true.

In your case, you must prove that, for all $x_1,x_2$, $$\frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1}\neq f'(c)$$

To do that, answer these questions first:

- What is $f'(c)$ equal to?
- What is $f(x_2)$ equal to?
- What is $f(x_2)-f(x_1)$ equal to?
- What is $\frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1}$ equal to?

Once you have the answer to these questions, just use one more hint: remember the factoring that looks something like this:

$$a^3-b^3 = (\cdots)(\cdots)$$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $c = 0$. It is fairly evident that $f'(0) = 0$. Thus, we seek

$$\frac{f(x_2) - f(x_1)}{x_2 - x_1} = 0$$

Multiply through on both sides by the denominator and thus we seek

$$f(x_2) - f(x_1) = 0 \;\;\;\;\; \Rightarrow \;\;\;\;\; (x_2)^3 = (x_1)^3$$

An implicit assumption is that $x_2 \neq x_1$ (otherwise, the denominator given in the problem would be undefined).

Since $x^3$ is an injective function, $x_2 \neq x_1$ immediately implies $(x_2)^3 \neq (x_1)^3$ for all $x_1, x_2$. Thus, such $x_1, x_2$ cannot be found.